# How to troubleshoot photo import failure with Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell, jpeg

I can't get Shotwell to import my photos. They are all normal JPEG files from digital cameras, about ten thousand in total. How to I continue troubleshooting this, and get all my photos back into Shotwell?

I exported them from within Shotwell to a backup drive, prior to reinstalling Ubuntu 11.04. The export settings were: current format, original size, and export metadata selected. After exporting, I verified the files were all present, batch renamed them all with pyRename, and then opened a few at random to test. Now I've reinstalled and it's time to put them all back. I am having no luck at all. The only clue I have is the following error message in the ~/.cache/shotwell log:

> [WRN] No namespace info available for XMP prefix `lr'

I can open the files now after the reinstall, with Eye of Gnome. I can even import them into F-Spot, complete with tags and full EXIF data. Everything seems normal about the files, except they won't import into Shotwell.

I tried the default version of Shotwell, then the Yorba ppa (0.11.1 version), neither will import. They chug away, I hear the hard drive activity for a while, then I get a 'No photos or videos imported' message.

If this is the wrong place for this question can anyone suggest a better place to post it? Yorba's wiki & list of bugs did not give me any meaningful search results.

I've got a second backup of the images prior to all this, but they are untagged and unsorted. Did I just waste a week tagging and sorting all my photos for nothing?

Comment: Try to start Shotwell from command line and see if anything suspicious is logged on the console. Anyway - it's most likely a bug in Shotwell so the best place to report it is Yorba's bug tracker. Or get the source - fix the problem - send a patch :)

Comment: One note: the warning message you're seeing is coming from Exiv2, the metadata library Shotwell uses.  It's benign and has nothing to do with your photos not being imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the problem. When I batch renamed the files, I didn't preserve the file extensions (like .jpg). The image viewer handled them fine, and they showed up in Nautilus as JPEG type, but the missing '.jpg' on the end was the problem.

Shotwell is great, this was just user error. Do I get a bronze 'Idiot' badge now?

Answer (score 3):

We just released 0.11.2 a few minutes ago. Could you try upgrading to that first?
http://blog.yorba.org/lucas/2011/09/shotwell-0-11-2-is-here.html

If that doesn't help, please report a bug! We have a section on how best to report a Shotwell bug here:
http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellFAQ#I-found-a-bug-in-Shotwell-How-can-I-report-it